# Analyzing time series in depth

Tags: r, time-series, accuracy

I want to create a code which tests absolutely everything for time-series forecasting accuracy.

The current tests that I do are:

`bptest()` - tests against heteroskedasticity (to test if series should be transformed)

`gqtest()` - tests against heteroskedasticity (to test if series should be transformed)

`RMSE` - of in-sample `sqrt(mean((data-fitted values)^2))`

`MAPE` - of in-sample `mean(abs(100*(data-fitted values)/data))`

`MAPE` - of out-sample (removing the last 4 data points and running model) `mean(abs(100*(last 4 data points-the 4 forecasted points)/last 4 data points))`

`MAPE`- of forced out-sample (removing the last 4 data points and running model keeping the same parameters as the model of the full data)

`ACF and PACF` - of residuals `data-fitted values`

Here is a link that will show you my code so you can see what i have done so far and where/what i can add. I dont want to miss anything so as many suggestions as possible please! If you could explain them a little too that would be fab.

http://bit.ly/10iUY5Z

Comment: Are you asking about programming, or are you looking for specific statistics help? The best place to get a block of working code assessed is the Code Review Stack Exchange site, not here.

Comment: Both :) there is many statistical tests that can be done, and there may also be people who know how to implement the tests into R

Comment: I found [this nice piece](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tscharacteristics/) on Rob J Hyndman's blog and thought you could be interested. It's about automated analysis of time series. There are pieces of code ready for use and clear comments.